# How to solve the problem that the gassdb process cannot be started due to insufficient number of file handles?

Tags: open-gauss

When I start my database process, I found that I can not be start because file handles does not enough, how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually set the number of file handles, run the following command as the root user:
echo "* soft nofile 1000000" >>/etc/security/limits.conf
echo "* hard nofile 1000000" >>/etc/security/limits.conf